# Jquery .not() equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to implement a shortcut feature using a simple keystroke although I don't want to trigger the shortcuts when the user types in an input or a textarea.

I noticed that Jquery has a .not() method which allows this:

```
$(document).not("input").on('keyup keydown keypress', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if(event.key == 'n') {
        alert('n pressed outside of input');
    }
});
```

Therefore I am looking for an equivalent in plain javascript or a function that would check if the user isn't focusing an input.

```
document.onkeypress = (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'n') {
        console.log('n has been pressed! (input or not)');
    }
};
```

Comment: Check `event.target.tagName`

Comment: @ChrisG solved the issue. submit as answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but for your question: Jquery .not("input") equivalent in javascript is 
 document.querySelectorAll(":not(input)").

It returns an array of elements except input elements

Comment: Great, I felt bad about validating my own answer when it does not technically address the question's title.